# Azure function Event hub trigger

Tags: function, azure, events

I have created multiple Azure event hub trigger function in Azure Function App, which are configured  to use specific Event hub Consumer Group. But when an Event comes to Event Hub All event hub trigger are executing (they are not being triggered as per consumer group).

Can any one help on this problem? I am unable to figure out what configuration did i missed so, i am facing this problem

Answer (score 0):

Consumer groups provide a cursor in the event hub stream so multiple consumers can receive the same events. The behavior you describe is as designed.

Comment: I want to limit  execution on event hub trigger function to particular consumer group..can you please tell me how can i do that.

Comment: You can't do that. That's not what consumer groups are for. Read through this. It has pictures of what a consumer group actually does. Note that both consumer groups receive *ALL* events, they just maintain their own offset/cursor:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-what-is-event-hubs

Are you trying to route messages to a specific function based on some criteria? If so, amend your question.

Comment: thanks for your information ...actually i am unaware of what really consumer group are meant for.